# How can I create an object array in C++ and access the object string after memory allocation?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class

Now I am writing code for `newObjectArray(int size)` and `printTitles(Container *pArr, int size)` functions, dynamically allocated array memory with size elements, stored in `pArr` to print size words  After inputting and saving in the title of each element object of `pArr[]`, the title of all objects of `pArr[]` should be the output.
`printTitles(Container *pArr, int size)`
In the process of creating this function I keep having problems.  Precisely `cout << pArr[i]->title`.
This part gives error that operator `->` or `->*` is applied to "Container" instead of pointer type. How can I get close to and print a string in an object array?

I should get this as the output.
I type *3, 3, abc de f* and it should output `abc de f`.

```
menu? 3
element numbers of Container array[]? 3
Container(): arr = nullptr; size = 0;
Container(): arr = nullptr; size = 0;
Container(): arr = nullptr; size = 0;
input 3 words: abc de f
words: abc de f
```

This is the code I wrote, not finished yet. I tried replacing `pArr[i]->title` with `pArr[i].title` but this gave me a different error.
The error I get when I do this is *Cannot access member "Container::title"*. That's the error. And in `newobjectArray()` why `Container * pArr = nullptr;`. I wonder if this code is needed. This code is the code that existed from the beginning of the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/******************************************************************************
 * class Container
 ******************************************************************************/

class Container {
    string title;  
    int    size;   
    int    *arr;   
public:
    Container();
    ~Container();
    void setTitle(string title);
    string getTitle();
    void newIntArray();
    void newArray();
    void average();
    void rightRotateTitle();
    void findDeleteTitle();
    void inputIntArray();
};

Container::Container() {
    arr = nullptr;
    size = 0;
    cout << "Container(): arr = " << arr << "; size = " << size << ";" << endl;
}

Container::~Container() {
    cout << "~Container(): arr[" << size << "] deleted;" << endl;
}

void Container::setTitle(string title) {
    this->title = title;
   
}

string Container::getTitle() {
    return title;  
}

void Container::newIntArray() {
    cout << "element numbers of int array[]?";
    cin >> size;
}

void Container::inputIntArray() {
    cout << "input " << size << " integers: ";
    int *arr = new int [size];
    if (arr==NULL) {
        cout << "error" << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
        // cin >> (*arr + i)
    cout << "arr[" << size << "]: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    delete [] arr;
}
/******************************************************************************
 * Global functions
 ******************************************************************************/

void constructor() {
    Container c;
    c.setTitle("constructor-title");
    cout << "c.getTitle(): " << c.getTitle() << endl;
}

void intArray() {
    Container c;
    c.newIntArray();
    c.inputIntArray();
    //c.average();
}

Container *newObjectArray(int size) {
    Container *pArr = nullptr; 
    Container *pArr1 = new Container [size];
    string tmp;
    cout << "input 3 words: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cin >> tmp;
        pArr1[i].setTitle(tmp);
    }
    pArr = pArr1;
    return pArr;
}

void printTitles(Container *pArr, int size) {
    cout << "words: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << pArr[i]->title
}

void objectArray() {
    Container *pArr; 
    int size;       
    cout << "element numbers of Container array[]? ";
    cin >> size;
    pArr = newObjectArray(size);
    printTitles(pArr, size);
}

void inputTitle(Container* cp) {
    string s;
    getline(cin, s); 

}

void rotateTitle() {
}

void findDelete() {
}

/******************************************************************************
 * main()
 ******************************************************************************/

string menuStr =
"******************************** Main Menu *********************************\n"
"* 0.Exit 1.constructor 2.intArray 3.objectArray 4.rotateTitle 5.findDelete *\n"
"****************************************************************************\n";

int main() {
    while (true) {
        int menuItem;
        cout << endl << menuStr << "menu? ";
        cin >> menuItem;
        if (menuItem == 0)
            break;
        switch(menuItem) {
        case 1: constructor(); break;
        case 2: intArray();    break;
        case 3: objectArray(); break;
        case 4: rotateTitle(); break;
        case 5: findDelete(); break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Good bye!!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Write less code. Start with a simple class that wraps the dynamic array and performs two simple operations: 1) allocating the array 2) accessing elements in the array so that you can test 1. Then start adding other features you need one-by-one, testing as you go.

Comment: `Container *newObjectArray(int size)` -- `Container *pArr1 = new Container [size];` -- It's amazing how `std::vector` has been part of C++ for over 25 years now, and this style of coding is still being taught.

Comment: @Paul, I wrote practically no C++ in the 1990s and I *still* made use of the STL's `vector`. I think we can afford to be even more dismissive of this style of teaching.

Comment: @DrewDormann I've rewritten the entire code I've written so far and the error that happened again.

Comment: @user4581301 I want to declare an object array and access the strings in that object array, but when I try to access it, I get the above error less, how can I access it?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the selector operator "." and the dereference operator "->"?

Comment: The best advice I can give is to reiterate my earlier comment: Write less, not more, code. The more code you have to look for to find the bug, the more room it has to hide AND the more bugs you likely have. You can reproduce the mistake in about 10 lines of code, and at that point it's going to be hard to miss. In `pArr[i]->title`, `pArr` is a pointer to a `Container`. `pArr[i]` gets the `i`th `Container` after `pArr`, not a pointer to the `Container`. That means using pointer notation to access a member is not correct. You want  `pArr[i].title`.

Comment: When you use `pArr[i].title` the error is telling you that `title` is `private` within `Container`.  Either use `getTitle()` or make `title` public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pArr[i]` gives you an object at index `i`, that is not a pointer. So you have to use `.` instead of `->`.
Also `title` is private, try `getTitle()` instead.

You probably want to have something like this:

```
void printTitles(Container *pArr, int size) {
    cout << "words: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << pArr[i].getTitle();
}
```

Also, if you want to store *words*, like strings, then use `std::string`. (Which also handles the size for you.)
`int *arr;` and `int size;` , can be fine for an array of numbers, but also consider using `std::vector<int> list;` instead.

Comment: I tried using pArr[i].getTitle as you said, but this time I got an error like this 'A pointer to a bound function can only be used to call the function.'

Comment: And why isn't pArr a pointer? 'Container newObjectArray * pArr = nullptr;'  Since I declared a pointer variable in this code, does pArr not match the pointer?

Comment: `pArr` is a pointer, but `pArr[i]` is an object.  
`getTitle()` is a function. Did you add brackets and call it?

Comment: `getTitle()` is a function, you need to add brackets **after** a function to call it: `cout << pArr1[i].getTitle();` - please notice the brackets at the **end of the command**.